# Is it OK to use the same variable name in loops?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I just started programming in C++, and while coding I started noticing that I had a lot of for loops in my code, then I started thinking.

In for loops, when you create variables like: `for (int **i**=1;i<10;i++)`, what happens to the `i` after the loop is done?
Is it okay to create multiple for loops with the same variable name?
What about creating variables inside while loops?

Comment: in this case `i` is scoped to the `for` loop - it doesn't exist anymore after the loop is finished

Comment: Read about block scope here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope

Comment: `i`, `j`, `k` are conventionally understood to be indexes in loop, but if it makes it more clear, do use other names

Comment: Variables are local to loop statement scope and can't be used outside the loop scope.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ... what happens to the `i` after the loop is done?

It goes out of scope.

> Is it okay to create multiple for loops with the same variable name?

Yes, it's OK and widespread practice to do so.

> What about creating variables inside while loops?

Variables created inside of while loops are local to the while loops body. They are different from running variables created in the first part of the for loop header, which is executed only before the loop is entered first time.

Answer (score 1):

That depends, if you define the iteration value `i` inside the `for()` it is a local variable and is only declared inside `for()`, therefore you shouldn't use it for another loop inside the `for()` (besides you have a good reason for).

The following code for example will throw an error because the variable `i` is not declared outside the `for()` loop, that measn it is not accessable inside of the general `main(){}`:

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
  for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
    std::cout << "Iteration: " << i << std::endl;
  }
  std::cout << "Iteration outside of 'for': " << i << std::endl; // Error

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables created in a loop are variables that will not preserve that same value after the loop. It is only a temporal value. 
For example, this code will print i=10, as you are using the first "i" variable.

```
   #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 1; i<10; i++);

    cout << i;

    return 0;
}
```

We are in c++, so you can perfectly create another "i" variable in a loop, which will have a temporal value:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i<10; i++);

    cout << i;

    return 0;
}
```

And it will print the "i" not temporal value, which is 0.

Answer (score 1):

## what happens to the 'i' after the loop is done?

'i' will get the last value assigned in the condition inputted.

## Is it okay to create multiple for loops with the same variable name?

It will be depending on the syntax or statement used to run this code.

Good practice will be assigned different variable name for different declaration.

This will also fall in the first question. Also, you need to consider where this code
will be use is it in web, mobile application or a program.

## What about creating variables inside while loops? Thanks in advance.

Best practice is creating variables before doing any condition or statement.

Answer (score 1):

Generic names such as `i` `j` `k` are indeed commonly used, but it is actually a common bad practice. Variable name should properly reflect the purpose of the stored value. For example if it is used to index vector of items then it should be named `item_index` instead of just `i`. This may seem unnecessary verbose but such approach helps avoiding common bugs when variables with generic names are messed up, for example compare this `frobs[i] = some_frob; bars[j] = some_bar;` with `frobs[bar_index] = some_frob; bars[frob_index] = some_bar;`. Actually in such case not only indexing variable name should be non-generic, but variable type should not be not generic as well so conversion of one indexing type to another would require explicit cast. I think the situation with presence of several generically named variables is similar to [Three Star Programmer](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer) in the sense that it should never happen in properly written code.

Variables declared inside of loop scope are not visible outside of loop scope, so there is no problem. However construct `for(int i=1;i<10;i++)` is actually a syntax pitfall, as it ignores normal scoping rules and makes variable `i` declared outside of loop scope visible inside of scope. This is actually different from C, where declaring variable inside of `for` construct was prohibited. Basically

```
for(int i = 1; i < 10; ++i)
{
   // loop body
}
// i is not visible here
i = 42; // error
```

in C++ is a more compact equivalent to

```
{
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i < 10; ++i)
    {
       /* loop body */
    }
}  
/* i is not visible here */
i = 42; /* error */
```

in C.

Some compilers however may demonstrate non-standard behavior and allow variable declared inside of `for` construct be visible even after `for` loop has exited. For example Visual C++ with `/Zc:forScope-`

```
for(int i = 1; i < 10; ++i)
{
   // loop body
}
// i is still visible here
i = 42; // no error
```